# Returning a list of cells if the previous column is checked in a DatagridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've checked different codes for this but I'm not able to make effective use. I'm trying to check the value in 1st column which is boolean, if the column is checked then I need the data in the second column to be displayed in a text/list box (if multiple boxes are checked).

This is how it looks

```
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Methods",System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
                dt.Columns.Add("Select", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
                DataRow dr = null;



                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
               //Get the appropriate cell using index, name or whatever and cast to DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
               DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells["Select"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

               //Compare to the true value because Value isn't boolean
               if (cell.Value == cell.TrueValue)
               {
                   listBoxTemp.DataSource = cell.Value.ToString().ToList();
               }
                  //The value is true
            }
```

So for each selection made the respective string in 'Methods' has to be returned

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `row.Cells["Methods"]` to get the other adjacent cell in that row. You can insert it into a new list or do something else with it within that `foreach` loop.

ie. by modifying your existing code...

```
ListBox listBoxTemp = new ListBox();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells["Select"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
    if (cell.Value == cell.TrueValue)
    {
        listBoxTemp.Add(row.Cells["Methods"].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

You can also stop and later resume painting of the `ListBox` if you're iterating through a large amount of rows. [Refer to MSDN for an example of this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx)